# Hiding client side API calls

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api, security

I was making a small app (.Net web api backend service and angularjs for frontend) just to learn these frameworks, started to like project itself and thought it would be nice to deploy it...

However thing my .net rest service is as public as it gets, at the moment anyone can crud exposed through api objects and obviously I don't want somebody clearing my database once in a while. I don't really store any sensitive information, it's small web game, all I store in db are things like items, locations, game lobbies, players (only id, username and reference columns), but still deleting them will cause big problems somewhere.

So what how can I prevent this? My first thought is that it would be solved as long as nobody discovers my api address by somehow hiding API calls from user. Is this possible and realistic solution?

Comment: `"I don't want somebody clearing my database once in a while"` - Then don't give unauthorized users the ability to do that?  You can't hide what client-side code is doing/calling.  In order for code to be execute on the client, the client *by definition* needs to be able to read that code.

Comment: @David That's the thing I'm not really sure how to authorize them, when there's no passwords for users

Comment: Well, either you authenticate/authorize users or you don't expose that functionality.  There's really no way around that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot hide your API calls from the client, no matter what you do they could always use a packet sniffer like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to see what your app is doing.

You need to build a safer API that only allows users to manipulate their account. You can control their access by assigning tokens, like the way [oAuth](http://oauth.net/) works.

Comment: I'm not sure if traditional authentication will work in my case. By design players don't have passwrods. People just write their username (doesnt have to be unique) and either join a game lobby or create a new one, if he quits and comes again he just repeats this and creates another 'account'. 'Accounts' are deleted on web page closing.

Edit: There's a web game which has practically same system for users as mine   [spyfall](http://spyfall.meteor.com)

Comment: Do the players host the lobbies?

Comment: Yes, anyone can create or join it, but they are assigned just as players at the moment, host is no different than any other player who joined the lobby. Lobbies are small 3-8 players

Comment: Okay, so instead of having API calls that can delete your lobbies, have your lobby manager ping the lobbies to make sure they are still up. After they have been disconnected for a while, remove them from your lobby list. Your front-end shouldn't touch your DB, create an API that only gives users the minimum they need for your app to work.

Comment: Actually I had similar general idea of restricting client side access to deleting anything and deleting things automatically if they weren't updated for x amount of time, since games are quite short, and every time you restart, every player gets updated. Thanks, now i know i was thinking in kind of right way.