# Security back-end API to front-end framework

Tags: angular, reactjs, api, vue.js, frameworks

At my company we want to use a Javascript Framework(Vue/React/Angular) At this moment we are comparing all the frameworks to see which one suits best to our needs.

What we want do is the following:

**Backend API**(C#) **->** **Framework**(Vue/React/Angular)

To protect our data we want some security so not everyone can request our API (with some cracking), Our goal is that you can only reach the API with the client(website).

But the question is how should we do this without a login?

We looked into:

- CORS
- Throttling
- reCAPTCHA V3 (Not in China)

A combination of those above could work but is this the best we can do?

Comment: You can even add a custom token that only the client and the server knows.

Comment: Why does it matter which client your users are accessing the API with? If their browser can hit it, why shouldn't curl or postman?

Comment: @jonrsharpe To prevent data theft, the data is our core business.

Comment: But you're describing the same data being surfaced on a website without login. To put it another way: why do you prefer that people steal your data by screen scraping your website, rather than calling the API? You seem to be trying to solve the wrong problems.

Comment: @jonrsharpe If people want to steal data they will use tools for that, we know you can't prevent that. But if the API is accessible it's much easier/faster to get the data with the right requests.

Comment: Understand that what you're saying is you know this is pointless but you're doing it anyway. Ultimately that's your(/someone else in your company's) decision but it really shouldn't just be accepted. There's no technical solution to this within the constraints you've outlined, any request the browser can make can also be made from other HTTP clients, so change the constraints (e.g. rendering on the server, as suggested below, or at least doing any calculations server side so only what's absolutely needed for the markup goes over the wire, or adding auth - maybe the business model is broken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to tell you that there is absolutely no unbreakable way to restrict access to your API only from a specific client. In the end, your Javascript client makes HTTP requests to the API and these requests can easily be captured, studied and recreated in a testing tool (or even directly in Chrome!) or in another custom client.

A Javascript client running completely under the control of users can also be modified by them. Minifying and obfuscating can make this harder to do, but it won't stop anyone motivated enough.

Essentially, forget about any solution involving only the client because it's not trusted.

This then leaves only the server-side. The ideas you already gave can help, but the first question to ask (whose answer you didn't provide) is *which specific risks are we trying to protect against?*

If it's server overload for example, then throttling solves that mostly and you don't really need to care whether your own client actually makes the requests. If it's something else, maybe other solutions are available, but that information is crucial to finding the right solution.

#### Addendum

If you're not convinced that trying to control the client is pointless, have a look at this project that exists solely to scrape websites and/or provide different (more powerful) APIs to use them: https://weboob.org/

If you're so worried that the API will be abused, here are 2 (bad) mitigation methods:

- Don't provide an API! Render the HTML only on the server.
- Change the API every day or so and push out a new Javascript client to handle it.

However, neither of these prevents website scraping from the final rendered DOM unless you're ready to change its structure all the time as well.

Comment: _is which specific risks are we trying to protect against?_

We trying to make it harder for bad people to steal our data, and create their own site with our data. 

The data is our core business, but the site needs to accessible for consumers without a login.

Comment: @MattB added some more info

Comment: I upvoted on the basis of the server-side rendering suggestion; if this is such a concern why build an SPA and expose an API at all?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit related to [Hiding client side API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475129/hiding-client-side-api-calls)

What you can do:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)
https://obfuscator.io/
https://blog.jscrambler.com/how-to-protect-your-vue-js-application-with-jscrambler/

It will be harder to get those requests, but still - everyone can make a call to your API server, it will require just more time.