# How to secure url + data in VUE 3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I want increase security in my VUE 3 web apps.
I want to make sure that my ajax urls+data are not exposed and can't be tempered with.
I am developing Vue js app.
https://prnt.sc/dMtoji7Y_z2a
want to stop end client from knowing urls+data i am passing via ajax.

I want to stop anyone from knowing ajax urls.
End if exposing can't be stopped than how to stop anyone from tempering with them.
Securing url+data is the aim

Comment: It might be next to impossible to mask the URL in Front-end apps, however, what you can do is have a proxy API server that will be accessed by the app, and in turn the proxy server will hold all the private API[URL] holding your actual server-side code.

Comment: You can't hide anything from client, because your Vue runs on client side, so he has all the data that is needed to run request (e.g. importing request to Postman with all needed headers and altering data)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hiding client side API calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34475129/hiding-client-side-api-calls)